# IndentationError: unexpected indent Python timeit() Method

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, runtime

I'm new to python when am learning Time Complexity concepts got to know about time() and timeit() methods. When am trying to execute below program getting an error **"IndentationError: unexpected indent"**. Can Some body throw a light on what's the issue exactly here

```
import timeit
setup_code = "from math import factorial"
 statement="""for i in range(10):
    factorial(i)"""   
 print(f"Execution time is: {timeit.timeit(setup = setup_code, stmt = statement, number = 10000000)}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your indentation was a little bit wrong

instead of:

```
import timeit
setup_code = "from math import factorial"
 statement="""for i in range(10):
    factorial(i)"""   
 print(f"Execution time is: {timeit.timeit(setup = setup_code, stmt = statement, number = 10000000)}")
```

try:

```
import timeit
setup_code = "from math import factorial"
statement="""for i in range(10):
   factorial(i)"""   
print(f"Execution time is: {timeit.timeit(setup = setup_code, stmt = statement, number = 10000000)}")
```

Comment: if something is wrong again just ask me ^^

Comment: hey statement got executed thanks for that @maxthecomputersciencefox ... That would be great if you could explain little more